# PHP After Input Query when redirected to the main page, It isn't showing the recent added data until I refresh the page

Tags: php

I have 3 PHP pages:

**form.php:**

It is a form page to get details from the user and submit to input.php.

**input.php:**

It is a backend PHP page where the posted vars from form.php will be inserted into the database.

**index.php:**

It is the main page where the data saved in the database is shown in a table.,

Now the problem is:

When I submit the form.php it redirects to input.php where the posted data is stored in DB and then redirects to index.php. 
But when the index.php page opens, it won't show the recently uploaded data through input.php until I refresh the page.

My code goes as:

**form.php:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" id="adddelete" action="input.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" form="adddelete" value="<?php echo ($row2["id"]); ?>"/>
     <div class="panel-body">                                  
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Name : </label>
                <label><input type="text" name="name" style="width:200px;"/></label>
         </div>                               
     </div>
    <div class="panel-body">                                  
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Price : </label>
             <label><input type="number" name="price" style="width:200px;"/></label>
         </div>                               
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">                                  
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Category : </label>
                   <label ><select name="category" style="width:200px; height:30px;">
                            <option value="egglesscakes">Eggless Cakes</option>
                            <option value="photocakes">Photo Cakes</option>
                            <option value="cupcakes">Cup Cakes</option>
                            <option value="sugerlesscakes">Sugerless Cakes</option>
                            <option value="cheesecakes">Cheese Cakes</option>
                            <option value="premiumcakes">Premium Cakes</option>
                            <option value="tiercakes">Tier Cakes</option>
                            <option value="barbiecakes">Barbie Cakes</option>
                            <option value="kidscakes">KLids Cakes</option>
                            <option value="cartooncakes">Cartoon Cakes</option>
                            <option value="birthdaycakes">Birthday Cakes</option>
                           </select>
                    </label>
                </div>                                
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">                                  
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Description : </label>
                      <label><textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" style="width:300px; height:100px;"></textarea></label>
                </div>                                
           </div>

            <button class="userprofiledelete" form="adddelete" type="submit" align="center"> ADD </button>
</form>
```

**input.php:**

```
<?php include('index.php'); ?>

<?php

$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "databasename";


$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

$category = $_POST['category'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');


$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO cakes (name, price, category, description, date2)
VALUES ('$name', '$price', '$category', '$description', '$date2')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("You have succesfully updated product")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="index.php"></a>';
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

**index.php:**

```
<table class="table table-hover" >
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Added At</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM cakes ORDER BY date2 DESC";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {                               
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {                                   
?>

<tr >
      <td><a href='acakessub.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>'><?php echo ($row2["name"]); ?></a></td>
      <td><a href='acakessub.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>'><?php echo ($row2["price"]); ?></a></td>
      <td><a href='acakessub.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>'><?php echo ($row2["category"]); ?></a></td>
     <td><a href='acakessub.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>'><?php echo ($row2["date2"]); ?></a></td>                                                  
</tr> 

<?php     }
         } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Hope I'm clear with my problem. Please Let me know if I'm not clear.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how you go to index.php page ???

Comment: Are you clicking the link:- `echo '<a href="index.php"></a>';` to go to `index.php`??

Comment: it's a caching issue. Do not use JS for redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Your Common Sense says ***(`it's a caching issue. Do not use JS for redirects`)***

1.remove `<?php include('index.php'); ?>` from `input.php`

2.Use php `header()` insted of `<script>` to redirect

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  header('Location:index.php?message=success'); //remove other code.
}
```

3.On `index.php` check message and show message accordingly:-

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] =='success'){
   echo "record inserted successfully";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, @AlivetoDie. Apart from that, as you mentioned, I have added the "record successfully" message in the index page, but it shows as plain normal text on top of the header. How to make it look like a pop up over index page with some CSS effects.

Comment: instead of `echo "record inserted successfully";` you can add `alert` code here what you did in previous code

Comment: And another thing, apart from the posted question., Like when we are signing up in to stack overflow it asks what skills we know, so when you type "HTML" an auto dropdown comes and selects as HTML5 as a skill.and an "x" mark for every skill you choose, ... what is that 'keyword autoselect' code called and where can i find the code for it.,.

Comment: this is called  autocomplete mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you include your `index.php` in `input.php` in the first line. Try putting that include at the end of the file, so that the database entry is written and could be used in your `index.php`. If you want to have your success message on the page write it to a variable and use it in your `index.php` file.